# Simple web aplication (Tomcat) performance dashboard

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets

I was wondering if anyone could point me to right solution for simple performance dashboard for my web application. Technology stack: Tomcat + Springframework.

I was looking int OpenCore, but seams that their dashboard is quite expensive.

I would like to have easy access to memory usage and **response times**. I could try to write my own solution, but I would rather to not invent the wheel.

Googling for a while just gave me OpenCore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to monitor Tomcat (and many other Java apps, too) is [JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html).

After you [start Tomcat with JMX enabled](http://thiamteck.blogspot.com/2007/11/enable-jmx-on-tomcat-5-and-above.html), launch `jconsole` and connect to Tomcat process. You should see loads of things; all of this data is accessible from within your webapp.

In order to get response times, you need to look at `Catalina` → `GlobalRequestProcessor` → `http-<yourPort>` → `Attributes` section. It has `processingTime` and `requestCount`; from these you can get the average if necessary.

To get heap memory usage, look at `java.lang` → `Memory` → `Attributes` → `HeapMemoryUsage` and `NonHeapMemoryUsage`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this tip. I already use JMX console, but I was rather looking for something lighter. But I will give it another try.